# Swagger-ui lanza el error "TypeError: property is undefined" al renderizar el fichero swagger.json

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

Swagger lanza el error `TypeError: property is undefined` por la consola Javascript cuando intenta renderizar el fichero "swagger.json" generado por el módulo swagger-core que he integrado en la API que estoy desarrollando con Jersey (Java).

Al parecer dicho error tiene que ver con el siguiente método:

```
public ArrayList<ProductoStock> generarEntradaStock(EntradaRecurso entrada)
```

Si modifico la cabecera de dicho método de forma que, por ejemplo, retorne un `ArrayList<Integer>`, swagger-ui genera correctamente la documentación.

Para el desarrollo de esta aplicación estoy utilizando swagger-core 1.5, en concreto la librería `io.swagger:swagger-jersey-jaxrs:1.5.0` para Jersey (Java), el cual genera correctamente el fichero "swagger.json", y la última versión de swagger-ui (2.1.3).

Comment: disculpa, es java o javascript?

Comment: java. Voy a intentar aclarar un poco más la cuestión

Comment: estaba revisando preguntas sin respuestas, y me tope con esta, por lo que entiendo usted encontro la solucion, quizas podria ponerla como respuesta, asi no apareceria como sin respuesta, podria ponerla como wiki o no eso seria decision suya, solo es un simple comentario saludos

Comment: Añado la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer, la versión 1.5.0 de swagger-core tiene algunos problemas para procesar arrays. Por lo que actualizando la librería a la versión 1.5.4 se resuelven los problemas: `io.swagger:swagger-jersey-jaxrs:1.5.0`